# ~/.zshrc alias with a space

Tags: macos, zsh, zshrc

I have a bad habit of putting spaces in my folder/file names. Today it bites me.

I have a folder called `NFB Lab` in which I installed NFB Lab. I wanted to add the shortcut/command nfb and pynfb to the `~/.zshrc` file to start the main python script from anywhere.

I edited the `~/.zshrc` file through nano with:

```
alias nfb=/Users/mathieu/Documents/NFB\ Lab/pynfb/main.py
alias pynfb=/Users/mathieu/Documents/NFB\ Lab/pynfb/main.py
```

I also tried:

```
alias nfb="/Users/mathieu/Documents/NFB Lab/pynfb/main.py"
alias pynfb="/Users/mathieu/Documents/NFB Lab/pynfb/main.py"
```

Neither works, I always get:

```
zsh: no such file or directory: /Users/mathieu/Documents/NFB
```

How can I solve this without uninstall/reintsall of NFB Lab?

Comment: Putting spaces in file names is not a bad habit. Writing scripts that assume file names *won't* have spaces is.

Comment: @chepner As someone who writes Makefiles for a living, I happen to disagree with your first sentence :-)

Comment: I consider it a failing of `make` that it can't easily handle filenames with spaces :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll need to escape the space (`\` ), for example, take a look at my [sublimetext3](/questions/tagged/sublimetext3) alias;

```
alias sub='/Applications/Sublime\ Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl'
```

---

Otherwise, take a look at [ZSH functions](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Intro/intro_4.html). There are many more options compared to aliasses;

For example, run python script with arg as path, then create an alias calling that function

```sh
function runpy() {
    python3 "$@"
}
alias runx="runpy '/tmp/dir with space/py.py'"
alias runy="runpy '/tmp/dir with space/py_second.py'"
```

Comment: It works perfectly. Thank you! I used the second part of your answer to start the application in python and avoid token error/starting the app with bash.

Answer (score 1):

You need two backslashes.

```
$ mkdir "f oo"
$ alias f="cd f\\ oo"
$ f
$ pwd
/home/foobar/tmp/f oo
```

Comment: This syntax did not work for me: alias nfb=/Users/mathieu/Documents/NFB\\ Lab/pynfb/main.py

Comment: @Mathieu Did you forget the double quotes?

Comment: Maybe.. I'm not so sure why it didn't work here while it worked with alias pynfb='/Users/mathieu/Documents/NFB\ Lab/pynfb/main.py'

Comment: @Mathieu That's because double quotes are different from single quotes. You have to use the exact syntax of `alias foo="bar\\ baz"` or it will not work.

Answer (score 1):

Considering the confusion caused by backslash inside single or double quotes, here is one alternative :

```
alias nfb="'/Users/mathieu/Documents/NFB Lab/pynfb/main.py'"
alias pynfb="'/Users/mathieu/Documents/NFB Lab/pynfb/main.py'"
```